# CORS request to get WWW-Authenticate header

Tags: javascript, cors, http-authentication

I'm trying to make a CORS request to a server that I know in this case will require authentication.  What I don't want to do though is the browser popup the dialog to prompt for credentials.

In an ideal world I would,

1) issue the CORS request

2) See that it requires Authentication

3) get the WWW-Authenticate header

4) reissue the CORS request with the new authentication header set

When I attempt this the initial request comes back and the browser immediately prompts for a username and password.

Behind the scenes I have a way to authenticate myself if I can get the WWW-Authenticate header to check to see if it is digest or basic auth that is required.  At this point the header is null as far as the XMLHttpRequest is concerned.

I'm assuming to save me from myself the browser has stripped it off because it will handle it.  The status is also now set to 0 instead of 401.

```
var client = = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', src, true);

client.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (client.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && client.status === 200) {
    // Success
}

if (client.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && client.status === 401) {
    var wwwHeader = client.getResponseHeader("WWW-Authenticate"); /// <-- this is nullwhenever I use a CORS request
    // create authentication header to reissue request
}

if (client.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && client.stataus === 0) {
    // the browser hates me and what I have done to it  <-- this is where I end up
}
```

Have I fundamentally misunderstood something here?

Edit: Updated comment in example

Comment: Same problem here. @Saurbaum did you solve?

Comment: @eLBati Sadly not. It just became not enough of a priority to ever fix.

Comment: Downvote. Check your code.

Comment: Well I've checked and the code is definitely code. More seriously this is ancient and abandoned and in the past 7 years since I originally wrote it who knows how things have changed.